# iOS 12 stringFromDate method returns incorrect value

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios12

In iOS 12, I have noticed that the `[NSDateFormatter stringFromDate]` method returns an incorrect value on a simulator iPad, but the correct value on a physical iPad.

Example code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"c"];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
// Returns correct value on both physical and simulator iPads (eg. Fri Oct 19 15:39:53 2018)

NSString *currentDateAsString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate];
// Physical iPad: 5 (correct)
// Simulator iPad: 6 (incorrect)
```

Both iPads have the same date/time settings (eg. same timezone). What is the cause of this bug?

Comment: Updated original question with the incorrect value

Comment: Well, what the format `"c"` shows would depend among other things on what that machine thinks is the first day of the week. That can differ from machine to machine. Also you say they have the same settings but we have no reason to believe that. There are lots of subtle ways they might differ. The `"c"` format is a very blunt instrument; try a format with more information in it.

Comment: Essentially I need the current day of the week as a number, and `"c"` appears to fit that requirement. This problem did not occur in previous iOS upgrades, but it has appeared now from iOS 11 to 12.

Comment: I don't deny any of that! I'm suggesting that you explore a little further to see what's going on here, by trying some more informative formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the first weekday](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1408310-firstweekday) on your real and simulator iPads to see if they match:

`NSCalendar.current.firstWeekday`

and take that value into your calculations on the weekday taken from the date formatter.

The first day of week on iOS depends on the Region settings. Double check the settings in Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Region on both your real and simulator iPads. Also, it may worth to check the first day of week on your Mac in System Preferences -> Language & Region -> First day of week too.